# grouping actions to offer suggestions

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to offer artist suggestions based on our user's favorites.

Our table looks like:

> user_id | artist_id
>   1 | 4
>   2 | 4
>   1 | 3
>   4 | 4
>   6 | 2
>   6 | 3
>   4 | 3
>   2 | 3

So if a random user is looking at artist_id 3, the code should query the database for other users who have favorited artist_id 3 and find the most common artist links between them

In this case, artist_id 3 is favorited by users 1,3,4,6... and of those users, there is the common artist_id 4 that should be picked out (because it appears the most).

So how should I efficiently do this?

Do I do several queries?  First one to grab all user_ids who have artist_id 3, then I grab all favorites for those user_ids and group accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.artist_id
FROM tbl t1
INNER JOIN tbl t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    AND t1.artist_id <> t2.artist_id
WHERE t1.artist_id = 3
GROUP BY t2.artist_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE A,
(
    SELECT artist_id,user_id
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE artist_id=3
    GROUP BY artist_id,user_id
) B
WHERE A.user_id=3 AND
      A.user_id = B.artist_id;
```

Comment: Why are you joining user_id to artist_id? The derived table is an unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from MySQL expert but something similar might work. But it is tricky with mysql subselects - they tend to do crazy things when applied on big data amounts.

```
    SELECT artist_id FROM `table` WHERE
user_id IN (select user_id from `table` where artist_id = 3)
and artist_id != 3
group by artist_id 
order by count(artist_id) desc
limit 1;
```